# FoxitReader printing without preview

Tags: vb6, foxit-reader

I would like to print a .pdf file without preview. I used the "FoxitReaderOCX.ocx" component for this, but before it goes to printing, a preview is called. Is direct printing possible in this case?

My code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  FoxitReaderOCX1.OpenFile ("C:\test_raport_PDF.pdf")
  FoxitReaderOCX1.PrintFile
End Sub
```

I will be grateful for your help :)

Comment: Probably best to ask questions like that in the [Foxit forums](https://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader).

Comment: [foxit-reader] has 33 questions here... which is fairly small... depends who follows the tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxit-reader